# CSS is not applying after loading

Tags: django, static

Help Post:
I have a project built with django 2.1.5
it works fine in my machine, works fine when I transferred it to another machine but doesn't work on my another friends machine.
Everything looks fine, just the static files are not applying. Here's what I have done so far:
1. created new project
2. cleared browser cache several time
3. run collectstatic command
4. run findstatic command (shows the right path)
5. used chrome debugging tool to se whether my static files are loading or not (found everything is loading fine)

I don't understand where's the problem is...it doesn't show any error or nothing...never faced such weird problem before. Same settings, same files run in two machine but don't in one? Found no solution anywhere, never heard even. Anyone can suggest anything?